# AngularFire@7.1.1: NullInjectorError: No provider for Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm getting the following error message with my Angular 12 app: `NullInjectorError: No provider for Firestore!`

Firestore is initialized both the old and the new way in my **lazy loaded** `admin.module.ts`

```
import { connectFirestoreEmulator, getFirestore, provideFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/firestore";

...

imports: [
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    provideFirestore(() => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        if (!environment.production) {
            connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, "localhost", 8080);
        }

        return firestore;
    }),
]
```

Also setting up Firebase both ways in my `app.module.ts`

```
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from "@angular/fire/app";
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire/compat";

...

imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
]
```

And finally, using Firestore in one of my services, (let's call it `foo.service.ts`) that is being provided by my `admin.module.ts`

```
import { Firestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

...

export class ScanRepositoryService {
    constructor(private firestore: Firestore) {}
}
```

From what I can tell, I'm following the AngularFire documentation pretty strictly, still, getting this error message about my service can't resolve Firestore. Re-installing the whole node_modules and re-compiling the app with both dev and production flags did not help. Any other idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by removing all the "old" non-modular usage of Firestore, leaving only the version 9+ parts.